# Can XSL-FO be use to created MANY documents?

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I am looking into various technologies associated with formatting data into document form.  There are many software platforms to do so, but most are quite expensive.

I stumbled upon XSL-FO and have been looking deeper into it to see if it may fit my needs.  But so far I have not been able to answer this question.  Can it be used to create multiple documents into a single stream?

FOP can create AFP (the print language my company uses for mass printings) and it works pretty well (I would need to do more font configuration to make it truly worthwhile).  But I have not yet seen any evidence that XSL-FO can create hundreds, thousands, or in my case hundreds of thousands of documents (statements) in a single print stream.

One more question for anyone who knows FOP... can it index (TLEs, NOPs, etc.) documents in an AFP stream?

***ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:***

I do not have any code to show/share because this little project is in the research phase.  I would dearly love to know if XSL-FO will meet my needs BEFORE I spend the next 4-6 months buried in books, tutorials, and manuals, coding something together, only to find it can't do what I need.

What I am looking for is a way to create multiple documents in a single print stream (AFP) for spooling to commercial printers.  I found fop as an open-source Java-based converter for turning XSL-FO to AFP (or PDF, or a host of other outputs).

For these purposes, a document may be defined as follows: a group of pages/impressions that begin with page 1.

So far, I have not seen how XSL-FO can produce anything other than a single document at a time.  Granted, my foray into XSL is in its infancy, which is why I've sought answers here.

Some potential answers to this question that would not surprise me might be:

"Yes, XSL-FO can do this... look into the *fo:new-document* tag."

"No, XSL-FO is intended to create a single document.  To produce multiple documents, you need to either use a third-party piece of software or post-process the XSL-FO to "fake" multiple documents."

If the answer is yes, then I will pursue this further.  If the answer is yes, but it costs money, then I will pursue other avenues that also cost money but that are far easier to develop with.  If the answer is no, then I will again pursue other avenues.

I hope this clarifies my query.  Anyone have some good insight for me?

***MORE INFO:***

This looks promising: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/output.html#afp

Answer (score 1):

Certainly XSL FO can be used to do such a thing: (1) producing many individual documents from a single large (repetitive document), (2) producing a large document from a single large document or (3) even combinations of this ... simultaneously. Refer to the concepts posted within this whitepaper:

http://www.renderx.com/solutions/large_report_formatting.html

with details here:

[PDF Report](http://www.renderx.com/files/documents/RenderX_Large_Reports_Formatting.pdf)

These apply to RenderX and how it functions. In such a solution, a single XML input could represent many thousands of repeating invoices. You can split in chunks, send to multiple simultaneous threads of composition engines running in separate threads, JVMs, even on different machines and assemble or whatever desired to create the desired output. Because you can parallelize the composition step, you can scale with threads, cores, CPUs and machines even to get the performance you need. Such methods are in production in major organizations throughout the world.

We do not evaluate or test FOP, the concepts presented would require a completely thread safe renderer as is XEP and a rendering thread controller as is EnMasse. XEP is an FO renderer and does supports AFP with TLEs, etc. as one output format (also PDF, PDF Forms, Postscript, XPS, PPML, SVG, XHTML ...).

Comment: @Hinata Hyuga: SE rules require one to disclose their affiliation with the company, especially if their answer is primarily about the company's products. Be careful removing signatures with such disclosures as it make the **editor** to violate SE rules.

Comment: Well my original post did include "Kevin Brown, RenderX" but was edited out. please point to specifics on how to modify the post to show a proper affiliation that will not be edited.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that works within the cheap-as-free XSL-FO framework, not a purchase-our-software solution.  There are tons of purchasable solutions out there for this type of thing, but the whole concept of "home-grown" is to develop in-house as much as is feasible.  Once the credit cards come out, the nature of the solution usually changes dramatically.

Comment: @mswanberg Then your question may need some clarifications. Creating "many documents" may be (1) splitting a source XML into chunks and processing them individually via, e.g. shell scripts; (2) making stylesheets to output separate XSL-FO documents and then rendering them individually into output formats; (3) splitting a rendered XSL-FO into chunks; (4) splitting (or tagging) a result document for enterprise printing devices like AFP printers. Please consider indicating your chosen approach, your existing code, and the actual problem you are facing with.

Comment: write a very similar framework for the cheap-as-free FOP framework (XSL FO is not a framework, it is a standard where free and not so free applications can be designed to support) and rifle the code for elements where it may not be multi-threaded. As it is open source, all the information should be there.

Comment: @bytebuster - Not sure I know how to handle this.  I've never heard anyone question what "many documents" could mean.  Your potential answers for this are 1) why would I ask if XSL-FO could create many documents if what I want to do is split XML?  2) This could be accomplished with (1).  3) Same thing.  4) This is the closest to what I mean.  I'll update my original question to clarify what I'm asking.